# Send data between 2 Async class

Tags: android, asynchronous

I want to retrieve information from one async task in an other async task. The two are in a same Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> status) {

  ...

  Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, SendQuestionChooseAsync.class);
  intent.putExtra("image1", image);
  intent.putExtra("answer1",answer);
}
```

SendQuestionChooseAsync my seconde async activity.

In SenQuestionChooseAsync I do that but the value is null:

```
String image1 = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("image1");
```

How can I send data from an async to another async?

Thanks.

Comment: Just declare a member variable in the activity? Intents are for passing information between different Activities.

Comment: What it's the image type? Like you're doing, will only work in case it's a Serializable type.